# Correctly reload an activity with a pager with more then 3 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

When I first start the application it works correctly, but when application goes in background (by clicking home button) something goes wrong.
My Activity has a pager with 4 fragments, and when I reload Activity some of the fragments are lost (nothing is displayed).
I read that the pager keeps memory of the current fragment, the one on the left and the one on the right. How can I solve such a problem?

Comment: You need to debug your code, specifically your adapter.

Comment: post you code or see this  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228502/viewpager-tabs-recreated

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034195/viewpager-tabs-fragment